# Nested Angular elements throwing ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError

Tags: angular, angular-elements

I've done some research around this issue, now I'm not sure it's a bug or something wrong with my implementation.

I've got an element which uses a service to fetch some data, then it passes the data to a child element, but when I update the data, I've got that error.

### parent element

```
import { Component, OnInit, ViewEncapsulation} from '@angular/core';
import { TestService } from '../services/test.service';

@Component({
    selector: 'dm-element-with-service-test',
    templateUrl: './element-with-service-test.component.html',
    encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.Emulated
})
export class ElementWithServiceTestComponent implements OnInit {
currentCount: number;

constructor(private testService: TestService) { }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.testService.count.subscribe(count => this.currentCount = count); 
    }

    count() {
        this.testService.addCount();
    }

}
```

### parent element view

```
<div>
    <button (click)="count()">count</button>
    <element-test [myNumber]="currentCount"></element-test>
</div>
```

### child element

```
import { Component, OnInit, ViewEncapsulation, Input } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'dm-element-test',
    templateUrl: './element-test.component.html',
    encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.Emulated
})
export class ElementTestComponent implements OnInit {
    @Input() myNumber: number;
    constructor() { }

    ngOnInit() {
    // do stuff...
    }
}
```

### child element view

```
<p>
    current number in this component: {{myNumber}}
</p>
```

### app module

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule, Injector, CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA } from '@angular/core';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { ElementTestComponent } from './element-test/element-test.component';
import { createCustomElement } from '@angular/elements';
import { ElementWithServiceTestComponent } from './element-with-service-test/element-with-service-test.component';


@NgModule({
    declarations: [
        AppComponent,
        ElementTestComponent,
        ElementWithServiceTestComponent
    ],
    imports: [
        BrowserModule
    ],
    providers: [],
    schemas: [CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA ],
    entryComponents: [ElementTestComponent, ElementWithServiceTestComponent]
})
export class AppModule {
    constructor(private injector: Injector) {
        const el = createCustomElement(ElementTestComponent, { injector });
        const el2 = createCustomElement(ElementWithServiceTestComponent, { injector });
        customElements.define('element-test', el);
        customElements.define('element-with-service-test', el2);
    }
    ngDoBootstrap() { }
}
```

### Index

```
<div class="tests">
     <element-with-service-test></element-with-service-test>
</div>
```

When I load the app, everything's fine, but if I click the count button I've got that error.

Answer (score 0):

That error will always happen when you change data passed from parents in child components. You should either

1) not do that

2) use `changeDetectorRef.detectChanges()` when you do modify data.

https://blog.angularindepth.com/everything-you-need-to-know-about-the-expressionchangedafterithasbeencheckederror-error-e3fd9ce7dbb4